# Visual Studio Team Services warehouse

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

http://localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx/GetProcessingStatus

When i try to get the status of the warehouse jobs the service is taking a long time to load say 15- 20 minutes and this has started suddenly it was working fine until couple of days back

Any idea on this ?

Comment: Did you check the status of the TFS Warehouse and Cube on your TFS AT machine? Does it still take a long time to load now?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some web services are processing when you access the Status.